# Terraform data.google_compute_network not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

This is the code block I am trying to execute... terraform 1.0

```
data "google_compute_network" "my-network" {
  name = "udemytestdel"
}

resource "google_compute_firewall" "firewall" {
  name    = "gritfy-firewall-externalssh"
  network = data.google_compute_network.my-network.name
  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["22"]
  }
  source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"] # Not So Secure. Limit the Source Range
  target_tags   = ["externalssh"]
}
```

And I keep getting this

````
│ Error: Missing required argument
│
│   with google_compute_firewall.firewall,
│   on vm.tf line 16, in resource "google_compute_firewall" "firewall":
│   16:   network = data.google_compute_network.my-network.name
│
│ The argument "network" is required, but no definition was found.```
````

Comment: I have tried self_link as well as ID but same result... the udemytestdel network does exist..

Comment: Try without data. in data.google_comp........  [eg](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_firewall)

Comment: that would work if the google_compute_network was a resource... no? ```│   on vm.tf line 22, in resource "google_compute_firewall" "webserverrule":
│   22:   network = google_compute_network.udemynetwork.name
│
│ A managed resource "google_compute_network" "udemynetwork" has not been declared in the root module.```

Comment: Perhaps try  network = google_compute_network.my-network.name

Comment: I am an idiot, was creating in a project where the network did not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding project name as well.

```
data "google_compute_network" "my-network" {
    name = "udemytestdel"
    project = "yourprojectname"
```

Comment: Also, you need to use self_link for network if it is shared (and in other project). Reference docs https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#network